# Swift uniform access principle

Tags: swift

Does swift support the [uniform access principle](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/UniformAccessPrinciple.html) ? As far as I can see the following [code](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID267) shows that it isn't:

```
@objc protocol CounterDataSource {
    optional func incrementForCount(count: Int) -> Int
    optional var fixedIncrement: Int { get }
}

class Counter {
    var count = 0
    var dataSource: CounterDataSource?
    func increment() {
        if let amount = dataSource?.incrementForCount?(count) {
            count += amount
        } else if let amount = dataSource?.fixedIncrement {
            count += amount
        }
    }
}
```

`incrementForCount` is a func and has to be accessed differently (as an "optional" implemented method), right?

Comment: So if it supports, what code would you write for this?

Comment: The description in your link points just to Swift's computed properties. What else is needed for "uniform access"?

Comment: Either I'm confused by this question, or the asker interpreted the linked article about uniform access principle significantly differently from me.

Comment: Swift does support it. When you access a property of an instance, your code does not know if it's stored or computed. Optional functions in protocols are different and do not impact this. They largely exist for compatibility with Obj-C, but nevertheless provide a means for a protocol to only require partial implementation. They are accessed differently, but consistenly.

Comment: @Darko The link is just the source of the code snippet

Comment: @J.Wang : 'fixedIncrement?', the same as the function. Again Quote Meyer: "[...] not betray whether they are implemented through storage or through computation"

Answer (score 0):

I think this question misunderstands the article about uniform access principle, and I'm not even exactly sure how protocols fit into the discussion here.

The article isn't necessarily particularly clear, but there are two keys:

1. This quote:

   > Whatever the language does, it's important that programmers don't violate the principle. Often you'll see conventions that subvert uniform access. An example of this might be saying that data accessors are named getAge while computed accessors are named calcAge. I make a point of naming my accessors the same way in either case.
2. And this graphic: [image]

So for this example, I have some class, `Person`, which has two properties we care about--age & birthdate.

There are two possible implementations of this class:

```
class Person {
    let birthDate: NSDate

    var age: Int {
        NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: birthDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil).year
    }

    init(birthDate: NSDate) {
        self.birthDate = birthDate
    }
}
```

Or...

```
class Person {
    let birthDate: NSDate
    let age: Int

    init(birthDate: NSDate, age: Int) {
        self.birthDate = birthDate
        self.age = age
    }
}
```

In one case we have a calculated age and in the other case we have a stored age.

But in both case, we access them in the same way.

The violation of uniform access principle comes into play if the computed property in the first case is replaced with a function: `calculateAge() -> Int`

The caller shouldn't care whether age is calculated based on birth date or is a stored property.  Swift has the tools that allow developers to write code without violating the uniform access principle.

Further more, the frameworks that we use when developing iOS & OS X apps do a good job of conforming to the uniform access principle.  Methods & property accessors are never named with a `get` or `calculate` prefix.  Properties can be implemented as computed properties (or, obviously, stored properties).  Methods can do calculations or simply return stored variables.  Nothing prevents any of this.

For completeness, taking the two `Person` implementations above, a violation of uniform access principle would look like this:

```
class Person {
    let birthDate: NSDate

    var calculateAge: Int {
        NSCalendar.currentCalendar().components(NSCalendarUnit.CalendarUnitYear, fromDate: birthDate, toDate: NSDate(), options: nil).year
    }

    init(birthDate: NSDate) {
        self.birthDate = birthDate
    }
}
```

Or...

```
class Person {
    let birthDate: NSDate
    let getAge: Int

    init(birthDate: NSDate, age: Int) {
        self.birthDate = birthDate
        getAge = age
    }
}
```

Comment: I agree. But as you can see in the example code, the property fixedIncrement is not accessed the same way as the function. The function needs an additional '?'. Doesn't this violate the uniform access principle?

Comment: No.  I don't even understand how you're relating the idea of optional protocol functions with uniform access principle.  The simple fact of considering all functions to be considered calculated and all properties to be considered stores is in itself probably a violation of uniform access principle that *you* are making.

Comment: Importantly, in your example code, `incrementForCount()` is a method whose name doesn't indicate or try to enforce stored or calculated values.  `fixedIncrement` *might* depending on your interpretation of this somewhat poorly named property.  But in neither case has it got anything to do with the fact that these are optional members of a protocol.

Comment: And I'd argue that your protocol isn't particularly well thought out.  If I were implementing this, and `incrementForCount()` made sense, then I'd simply make that the only member of the protocol and not make it optional.  @cakl Do you want to [chat about it](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105208/uniform-access-principle)?